# How to make a GraphQL api request from Django application?

Tags: django, graphql

I would like to know how to retreive data using the GraphQl api service and NOT to create the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like https://pypi.org/project/python-graphql-client/ for that.

Basically just look up 'python graphql request', it's not django-specific.